# how to make a clickable custom URI and send it to mail?

Tags: android, upi

How to make a custom URI like`upi://pay?pa=zeeshan@npci&pn=Zeeshan%Khan&mc=0000&tid=cxnkjcnkjdfdvjndkjfvn&tr=4894398cndhcd23&tn=Pay%to%rohit%stores&am=1010&cu=INR&refUrl=https://rohit.com/orderid=9298yw89e8973e87389e78923ue892` clickable and send it via gmail or facebook messenger to anyone . And when the recipient click on the link my application or any other application listening to this particular scheme open. i have tried sending it but the URI is not clickable hence the CHOOSER dialog don't pop up.

I guess the problem is, app like gmail or messenger is not recognizing this as a URL. So is there any workaround apart from contacting to apps developer team to add it in the list of clickable entries?

Comment: Hey, did you find an answer to this?

Comment: what is your query?

Comment: I just wanted to know if I can make a URL on a website which, when clicked on, would open a UPI application with predefined values